# How to convert without index array to index array

Tags: php

From $data I am getting array like

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [start_date] => 2018-07-27
    [end_date] => 2018-07-31
)
```

but I want array in this format how can I do this can anyone please help me I want array to be start with the index I am new here so any one please help me related this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [id] => 1
           [start_date] => 2018-07-27
           [end_date] => 2018-07-31
        )
)
```

Comment: Just add your current array in to one more array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this out:

This will be your array:

```
$arr['id'] = 1;
$arr['start_date'] = '2018-07-27';
$arr['end_date'] = '2018-07-31';

$ar[] = $arr; // What you have to do is this line
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar);
```

Output will be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [start_date] => 2018-07-27
            [end_date] => 2018-07-31
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?php

$myArray = [];
$myArray[0] = array(
'id' => 1,
'start_date' => 2018-07-27,
'end_date' => 2018-07-31
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jus add your first array to another array.

e.g.

```
 $first_array = [
    "id" => 1
    "start_date" => 2018-07-27
    "end_date" => 2018-07-31
];


$another_array = [$first_array];

//OR

$another_array = [
    "your_index" => $first_array
];
```